# Javascript keyword "this" becomes undefined

Tags: javascript, jquery, datatables, undefined, this

I am using DataTables to create a list of selectable phone numbers, my function is as follow:

```
function search(areacode) {
    areacode = typeof areacode !== 'undefined' ? areacode : 239;
      $("#did_search").fadeIn();    
      var table = $('#example').DataTable( {
            "bDestroy": true,
            "ajax": "/Portal/manage/search_bulkvs/" + areacode,
            "columns": [
                { "data": "did" },
                { "data": "city" },
                { "data": "state" },
                { "data": "action" },
            ],
            "columnDefs": [
            { "visible": false, "targets": 3 }
          ]
        } );

    $('#example tbody').on( 'click', 'tr', function () {
        var row_object = table.row( this ).data();
        $("label[for = did_label]").text(row_object.action);
        $('input[name="did"]').val(row_object.action);
    } );

}
```

The end of the function $('#example tbody') -- allows me to select the data from the table that I need and set the value of my label/input for form processing. However, after I run this function a second time I am unable to select this data anymore.

My debugging has led to this error: Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'action' of undefined

I thought that row_object would be defined every time that the function is run, but it looks like it isnt.

Does anyone have any suggestions as to how I can retrieve this data from the table after the function has been run more than once?

Comment: If the ajax call replaces the `tbody` element of the table, you will need to attach your delegated event handler to a non-changing ancestor (e.g. `$('#example').on` or even `$('#example').parent().on(`. You also want to avoid repeatedly setting up handlers if `search` is called multiple times (or call `off` before `on`).

Comment: @TrueBlueAussie Thank you so much for your help, I was able to achieve my desired results by using:

$('#example').parent().on( 'click', 'tr', function ()

Comment: Glad it helped. I will add that as an answer (I had it half written already) :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If the ajax call replaces the tbody element of the table, you will need to attach your delegated event handler to a non-changing ancestor (e.g. `$('#example').on` or even `$('#example').parent().on(`.

You also want to avoid repeatedly setting up handlers if search is called multiple times (or call off before on).

e.g.

```
$('#example tbody').off('click').on( 'click', 'tr', function () {
    var row_object = table.row( this ).data();
    $("label[for = did_label]").text(row_object.action);
    $('input[name="did"]').val(row_object.action);
} );
```

Answer (score 1):

Since you're using ajax, you need to bind your click object on each draw using [`DataTables.fnDrawCallback`](http://legacy.datatables.net/usage/callbacks), like this:

```
function search(areacode) {
    areacode = typeof areacode !== 'undefined' ? areacode : 239;
      $("#did_search").fadeIn();    
      var table = $('#example').DataTable( {
            "bDestroy": true,
            "ajax": "/Portal/manage/search_bulkvs/" + areacode,
            "columns": [
                { "data": "did" },
                { "data": "city" },
                { "data": "state" },
                { "data": "action" },
            ],
            "columnDefs": [
            { "visible": false, "targets": 3 }
            ],

            "fnDrawCallback": function(){
                $("tbody tr td",$(this)).click(function(e){

                    .... Your click code here ....

                });
            }

        } );
}
```

Comment: A delegated handler should have worked (and is more efficient), but it must be attached to a *non-changing ancestor*.

Answer (score 0):

It is not that `this` becomes `undefined`. This error message

```
Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'action' of undefined
```

usually means that you are calling a function from an `undefined` object (here is `row_object`), or the function you are calling (`action`) is not on the object.

Yes, the definition of variable `row_object` is fine. But I think you can `console.log` it to see whether it is assigned to some value correctly every time.